# Visual studio 2013 on linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2013, mono

I am trying to publish a ASP.NET application to Apache web server installed on Linux server using mono.
Please describe process to complete it briefly.

Comment: No, Just wanted to know how to port asp.net application on linux apache.I just  installed mono on linux.  but then what should i do to open .sln file of my asp.net project

Answer (score 1):

read this
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/porting-aspnet-applications/
i think you must change some `config` in `Web.config`, edit your `nuget` packages , recompile and release it agian.
consider that `monodevelop nuget` package manager can't run `powershell` scripts. thus you can't run and use some packages like Entity framework.
if you are using `MSSQLServer` as database ,perhaps its better to change it!
and use `postgresql` or others.